# Programmatic credentials to AWS for use with Nike's gimme-creds

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, credentials

I'm using Nike's gimme-creds CLI to get temporary access to AWS through OKTA.  I would like to do this programmatically in a Python program that can run on Windows/Linux/Mac.  Is there a way to do this without invoking the gimme creds cli as a process?  I couldn't find a library that does this for me in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Look in your python install directory (or where ever you installed gimme-aws-creds) and look for the command by that name.

Here's the code that is invoked from that command:

```
from gimme_aws_creds.main import GimmeAWSCreds

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        GimmeAWSCreds().run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit(130)
```

It looks like you can poke around the gimme_aws_creds.main library to see whats its doing. Look in your Lib/site-packages/gimme-aws-creds directory for the main.py module.